# FIltering results table on DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

I was wondering if there is any way to filter the results table after this has been generated, in DataGrip.

Sometimes I want to quickly search the results table itself by directly typing over it but all it does is edit the fields instead of searching for whatever I'm typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer about Ctrl/Cmd+F is right. But there are a couple more ways.

1. You can enter a filtering SQL condition (like in the WHERE clause) in the  field.

[image]

2. To filter a table according to a cell value, click this cell and select *Filter* by from the context menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can filter results with <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>

From the help link below:
Select the 'Filter rows' checkbox to see only rows with found matches.

By default, the search will only be on the current page of results. Consult the link for details on configuring to search so results, and details on other advanced search features.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/how-to-find-things-in-datagrip.html